# Select from list of values received from a subquery, possibly null

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

A (simplified version of my) query looks like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE column1
IN
(
    SELECT column1
    FROM table
    GROUP BY column1
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

This selects a list of id's where column1 has multiply occuring values (in other words, these are not unique). This works as expected with one exception: if the value NULL occurs multiple times (which is possible), no ids are selected. What would be the correct way to select ids of columns in case NULL turns out to be non unique?

Comment: is there an index on column1 like  (KEY (column1)) ?

Comment: Do you have some example data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`: exists is clearer (IMHO) and in most cases it is faster, too. (`IN (...)` needs to remove/suppress duplicates and NULLs, and thus: sort the set)

In this particular case: the aggregating subquery is only needed to find out that the group `count() > 1`. The query optimiser may not realise this, and calculate the complete group counts (over the complete set of rows) before comparing them to `1`.

```
SELECT tt.id
FROM thetable tt
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM thetable ex
    WHERE ex.column1 = tt.column1 AND ex.id <> tt.id
);
```

WRT the suppression of NULLs: the `WHERE ex.column1 = tt.column1` clause will always yield false if either `ex.column1` or `tt.column1` (or both) happen to be NULL.

---

UPDATE. It appears that the OP also wants the tuples with `column1 IS NULL`, if there a more of them. The simple solution is to use a sentinel value (a value that is not natively present in `columnn1`) and use that as a surrogate: (in the fragment below `-1` is used as a surrogate value)

```
SELECT tt.id
FROM thetable tt
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM thetable ex
    WHERE COALESCE(ex.column1, -1) = COALESCE(tt.column1, -1)
    AND ex.id <> tt.id
);
```

The other (obvious) way would be to explicitely check for NULLs, but this will require an `OR` clause and a bunch of parentheses, like:

```
SELECT tt.id
FROM thetable tt
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM thetable ex
    WHERE (ex.column1 = tt.column1 
          OR (ex.column1 IS NULL AND tt.column1 IS NULL)
          )
    AND ex.id <> tt.id
);
```

Comment: If both happen to be NULL, it should return true. That is what the whole question is about. I added OR ISNULL(ex.column1) AND ISNULL(tt.column1). Things seem to be working now.

Comment: Aha, in that case I am back to the old drawing board... (the solution will probably involve a double negation) BTW: the `IN(subselect)` always removes NULLs (and duplicates) from the result set.

Comment: No, it will not, given adequate keys/indices. (The aggregating subquery versions would or would not require full scans, depending on the phase of the moon)

Comment: How would you calculate the `COUNT(*) > 1 ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` without _at least_ inspecting two rows in the subquery ? In both cases, the subquery can bail out fast once it has found a result, but the plan generator/optimiser has to be smart enough to recognise this case. (postgres's one does and performs a special kind of pro/anti join)

Comment: I just tested (with postgres, obviously) and the third (`OR ... AND)` version was dramatically slower than the `COALESCE(column1, -1)` version. (this might depend on the proportion of NULLs, BTW) Adding an index on column1 helps in all cases.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Why did you choose `-1` by the way?

Comment: @user2180613 I chose `-1` because it stands out more in the text, and because most people don't use negative numbers in integer (KEY)fields. For your particular problam you might want to choose a different value.